# Difference between for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous

I recently notice that when I make async call in forEach loop like this:

```
fs.readdir(directory, function (err, filenames) {
    if (err) throw err;
    filenames.forEach(async function (filename) {
        let promise = await query.getItemByName(filename);
    });
});
```

it doesn't wait until the promise get resolved but if I do:

```
fs.readdir(directory, async function (err, filenames) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for (filename of filenames) {
        let promise = await query.getItemByName(filename);
    });
});
```

it wait for the promise to get resolved, I mean it fire the async calls one after another.

Can someone explain me why ?

What is the difference between `items.forEach(function (item){});` and `for(item of items)` ?